# Wrong row selected for edit after applying filter on DataTable Column

Tags: primefaces

Problem is like this:

Suppose there are records in dataTable with FruitType as A (meaning Apple) and O (meaning Orange). When the page is rendered, Records are filtered for Apple. When user filters on Orange and picks 10th record for editing in rowEdit mode, rowEdit listener is invoked on committing the changes. In rowEdit listener, rowEditEvent.getObject() is giving the 10th record of Apple Type.

My Code is attached below ....

```
<p:dataTable value="#{beanDetails.list_FruitDetails}" rowEditListener="#{beanDetails.handleRowEdit}" var="dataItem">
  <p:column filterBy="#{dataItem.FRUITTYPE}" filterOptions="#{beanDetails.options}" filterMatchMode="exact">  
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputLabel value="Fruit Type" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputLabel id="fruitType" value="#{dataItem.FRUITTYPE}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>


@ManagedBean(name="beanDetails")
@ViewScoped
public class Fruits implements Serializable{
public Fruits () throws Exception {
    private SelectItem[] options;
    options = new SelectItem[2]; 
    options[0] = new SelectItem("A", "Apple");
    options[1] = new SelectItem("O", "Orange");
}

public List<FruitDetails> list_FruitDetails;

public void handleRowEdit(RowEditEvent re) throws ParseException {
    FruitDetails pd = (FruitDetails) re.getObject();
    System.out.println(pd.ITEMCODE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As could not overcome the problem, I dropped the idea of having primefaces provided filters. Now I provided selectOneRadio to specify FruitType and loading the records of the specific Fruit Type in the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug on primefaces, this link states that it has been solved on the last version
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3467

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you, after a whole day working on this strange bug. finally I have found the answer! 
This works for me:
my environment:

```
primefaces 5.3
Mojarra 2.0.2
weblogic 10.3.3
```

The main problem is when we apply a filter on datatable, in primfaces, it store the filtered data in view state by invoking this method in **filter()**:

```
updateValue(filterdData)
```

After filtering, when we do a row select or row edit, the view must be restored before the actually method being invoked in order to update the **data in DataTable class with filtered data**.
Unfortunately, the `Mojarra 2.0.2` implementation doesn't handles the **restore view phase** as the newer versions, which result the **data in DataTable not being updated** before any other ajax posts after filtering.

So I just download the new `Mojarra 2.2.8` version and replaced the old one by adding this in my `weblogic.xml` file:

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

With this work around, the weblogic server will load new class files and the restore view phase is handled correctly as expected.

**Update:**
The implementation version of Mojarra does not necessarily to be exactly 2.2.8, actually, if you use an old version of servlet like 2.5, the newer version may cause other problems. So just use the newest Mojarra of the corresponding jsf version is enough. For example, 2.0.11 for jsf 2.0